# C# Hide a button when GridView on webpage is not shown

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I am using C# VS2005 and SQL Server 2005.

I have a GridView which imports data from 2 tables, and I have an 'Export' button below the GridView which allows exporting the result of the GridView data.

However, my export button is still shown when the GridView does not show. Is there anyway to hide a button conditionally and show it only when the GridView is shown? Below is an e.g. of my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MainPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Comparison.aspx.cs" Inherits="UserDatabase" Title="User Comparison" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:<ConnectionString> %>" SelectCommand="<SQL>" OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <!CDATA[

// ]]>
</script>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="btnExpExcel" runat="server" Height="23px" OnClick="btnExpExcel_Click"
        Text="Export" Width="200px" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Put both of them in a panel and hide the panel instead of hiding the grid.

Comment: both the button and the gridview have a .Visible property

Comment: @HasanKhan I have put both of them inside a panal, how do I set it to hide panal when my gridview is not shown?

Comment: @RUiHAO "hide the panel instead of grid view"

Comment: If i set the viability of the panel grid, it will always be hidden if I set it to false, even though there are data in the gridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [DataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) event to your Gridview. Check the rows in your gridview and set the visability accordingly.

ASPX

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ondatabound="gv_DataBound" 
     >
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void gv_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     btnExpExcel.Visible = GridView1.Rows.Count > 0;
     //The Following is actually better , but less readable
     //We cast the sender to Gridview. The sender is the control
     //initiating the event
     //btnExpExcel.Visible = ((GridView)sender).Rows.Count > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a panel on the page, and add the GridView and Button to it programmatically. Set the Visible property of the panel to true when you want to show it, and set it to false when you do not.

Comment: Why does he need to add them programatically?

Comment: Personal preference, actually. I've found that ASP.NET stuff is easier to manipulate when you add it programatically, as you kind of get tied to "static" items that are added to the page (and do not want to add / edit).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using DataSourceID, you can use DataSource and DataBind in code behind, that way you can check the data of data source to display or hide the Export button...
Something like this:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack){
  GridView1.DataSource = your_DataSet_or_DataTable_or_Anything;
  GirdView1.DataBind();
  if(your_DataSet_or_DataTable_or_Anything == null){
    btnExpExcel.Visible = false;
  }
}
```

^^

Comment: hi Hatake, what exatly do I have to put in for the GridView1.DataSource = your_DataSet_or_DataTable_or_Anything;? I tried GridView1.DataSource= SqlDataSource1; but it dosent work. It gave me the error <Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.>

Comment: Remove the part `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"` in aspx page. In code behind, that data source is the data you get from database or an array or anything as long as it contains data ^^

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the button within the gridview in a gridview footer template

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.footertemplate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do this way..

1. Create a method to bind the data in the gridview

   ```
   private void Export_Bind()
       {
           DataSet oDs_Export = new DataSet();
           oDs_Export = oFCC.GetExport(); ---> this is method which i have define in the Class Lib.
           if (oDs_Export.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
           {
               GridView1.DataSource = oDs_Export;
               GridView1.DataBind();
               lbGVCount.Text = oDs_Export.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
               btnExpExcel.Enabled = true;  

           }
               else
               {
                  btnExpExcel.Enabled = false;
                }
       }
   ```
2. Then this method in the page_load

   if(!IsPostBack)
   {

   Export_Bind();
   }

   If you find it useful, please mark it as your answer else let me know...